# How do I prevent lnd from participating in new channels?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels, ln-closing-channels

I have a `lnd` node that I would like to to cycle down completely. I would like to close all its channels and prevent that the node participates in any new channels while I'm waiting for the force-closed channels to mature.

What settings do I need to use in `lnd` to prevent my node from creating new channels, and to decline any new inbound channels?

Comment: LND has a ChannelAcceptor call which is [available in API](https://api.lightning.community/#channelacceptor) that allows you to block all incoming channel requests. However, I'm unsure if it is available in the RPC interface on the daemon with `ln-cli`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the option `--maxpendingchannels=0` to disallow peers to open channels to your node.